# How to write and run scripts in the Google Chrome Javascript Console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, console

I recently switched from Firefox to Chrome and I (probably) missed an important feature. I was used to test javascript snippets on FF from within the Firebug console this way: open the console, write the script and finally press CTRL + Return to execute the code.

It seems not possible to do the same in Chrome console, as when I type some code there and press return to start a new line the code is executed immediatly.

Is there a way to replicate the Firefox behavior on Chrome?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Install [Firebug Lite for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/bmagokdooijbeehmkpknfglimnifench). It has got a console.

Don't look for a full fledged Firebug. You will be disappointed :)</strike>

Oops,I didn't read properly at first. My bad!

In Firebug Lite, **take Console**. Then you will see a **tiny red up-arrow at the right corner**.
Click on it and you will get a **multi-line console**. Won't you?

Comment: Thanks. It would be a great workaround, if only I could be able to get Firebug Lite working on Google Chrome 10, instead that when I click on the bug icon it stays grey...!

Comment: @Guandalino: Try on Stack Overflow. It wont work on chrome extensions page

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is no explicit “multiline mode”.
But you can:

- Paste code (it will preserve multiline)
- Shift + Return to add a new line without executing the script

Related bugs:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30553
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=72739

Answer (score 3):

You can also hit Shift + Enter to start a new line without running the code in Chrome's console: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/tips-and-tricks#multiline-commands

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this:

1. Write `debugger;` and hit *Enter*, in the console tab
2. This takes you to the **Sources** tab; if not, make sure debugger breakpoints are active
3. Now you can write whatever you want in the **Sources** tab, which acts like a full IDE with features like newline and indentation
4. Select any part of your code to run, and right-click, choose `Evaluate in console`

Answer (score 2):

Better way of doing this using Chrome featue i.e **Snippets** where you can **write** **javascript** and **save** it in chrome developer console.
Its available underneath source inside developers tools while inspecting element.
[More info about the snippets can be find on this link.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets)

It was available in Chrome canary and I guess now it is available in default chrome browser also.